# Why does writing to an attached console wait for input?

Tags: c#, .net

When I write to a console attached to a Windows Application, the console waits for input.

```
    AttachConsole(-1);
    Console.WriteLine("test");
```

Pressing any key will return the user to the prompt.

Why does this happen? How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: You are chattering in the console of another program.  Usually Cmd.exe.  It is completely unaware of what you are doing, pressing the Enter key just does the exact same thing as it does when you don't do this, it redisplays the prompt.  Either use AllocConsole() so you'll get your own or use start /wait to get your program started so Cmd.exe stays out of the way.  Or explain why you think this needs to do something useful.

Comment: I'm implementing a CLI in a Windows Application, so that the application can either run on the command line or show a GUI. Not sure why you needed to know that. The question was: how do I force the application to return to the prompt?